# cx_freeze python 3.6 TypeError in sklearn file

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, pyqt4, python-3.6, cx-freeze

I am using PyQt4 to create a desktop app and trying to make it an exe file. My app opens after I build it with cx_freeze but my submit button (which sends data to another module) is not working. When I clicked submit I got a "No Module Found" error. It was saying that it could not find multiprocessing.pool in my sklearn/externals/joblib/pool.py file.

I went in the file and changed `from multprocessing.pool import Pool` to `from multprocessing import Pool` and it got rid of that error but gave me another error in the same file.

Now I get `TypeError: method expected 2 arguments, got 3`
referring to `class PicklingPool(Pool)` in that file

My app works fine as just .py files, so I don't understand why building with cx_freeze would give me a TypeError.

This is the init in sklearn/externals/joblib/pool.py:

```
class PicklingPool(Pool):

    def __init__(self, processes=None, forward_reducers=None,
                 backward_reducers=None, **kwargs):
        if forward_reducers is None:
            forward_reducers = dict()
        if backward_reducers is None:
            backward_reducers = dict()
        self._forward_reducers = forward_reducers
        self._backward_reducers = backward_reducers
        poolargs = dict(processes=processes)
        poolargs.update(kwargs)
        super(PicklingPool, self).__init__(**poolargs)
```

This is the init in multiprocessing/pool.py

```
class Pool(object):

    def __init__(self, processes=None, initializer=None, initargs=(),
                 maxtasksperchild=None, context=None):
        self._ctx = context or get_context()
        self._setup_queues()
        self._taskqueue = queue.Queue()
        self._cache = {}
        self._state = RUN
        self._maxtasksperchild = maxtasksperchild
        self._initializer = initializer
        self._initargs = initargs
        ...
```

Someone please shed light on this error.